# Right use about command handlers in ddd

Tags: command, domain-driven-design, factory

I'm creating an application in DDD. I want to know two things:

1- Is it correct to create the value objects (id, email, password) in the RegisterUserHandler? or I have to create a specific class that make that?

2- It is necessary to create a factory to a simple entity creation. I use userfactory to create the user, but I can put directly the next line: "$ user = User :: register ($ id, $ email, $ password);" in the RegisterUserHandler and delete the userFactory?

```
//class RegisterUserHandler
public function handle(CommandInterface $command)
{
    $id = Id::create();
    $email = Email::create($command->email());
    $password = Password::create($command->password());

    $this->userFactory->create($id, $email, $password);
}


//class userfactory
public function create(Id $id, Email $email, Password $password)
{
    $user = User::register($id, $email, $password);
    return $user;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necesarily need to use a factory to create `value object`s or `entities` if the creation is as simple as a constructor call. The principle that applies in this case is [KISS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

If the process contains *some* algorithm then you could extract it into a factory to move the responsibility elsewhere.